# Problemas con [Authorize] personalizado

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un `[Authorize]` personalizado que extiende de `AuthorizeCore` en el cual hago u na validación para que retorne un `true` o `false`, hasta ahi todo bien, si ingreso a mi pagina y no estoy logeado me redirecciona hacia mi pagina por defecto.

Pero al hacer un post de algún formulario esto no funciona, simplemente no hace nada, estaba depurando el código y efectivamente entra a la validación y retorna lo que debería retornar pero no redirecciona a donde debería, si no que no hace nada.

¿Quien sabe por que sucede esto o si estoy aplicando mal el `[Authorize]`?

```
public class MyAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isNotValid = true;
        if (isNotValid )
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si puedes pon el código que tienes hasta ahora, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: agregue el codigo

Comment: Tienes que anular el `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` que se especifica en [este enlace](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/customizing_authorize_attribute) (Traducir del Ingles)

Answer (score 0):

`[Authorize]` es un atributo que es incluído dentro del *namespace* `System.Web.Mvc`, si deseas usar un atributo personalizado y que lo puedas usar en donde desees deberá ser como anotación en un controlador.

Por ejemplo, si tu atributo de autorización se llama `MyAuthorization`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyAuthorization ]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

De esta manera, al entrar a la acción `Index()` primero se hará una llamada la clase `MyAuthorization`.

Answer (score -1):

has aplicado el authorize en las vistas?

```
<a href="<%=  @Url.Action("Home","Home") %>">


                        </div>

                        <% if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Usuario comun o admin"))
                            { %>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


                            <ul id="navegacion" class="nav navbar-nav ">
```

Comment: Creo que la pregunta va más relacionada a cómo hacer funcionar un atributo de autorización, no a limitar código en la vista dependiendo del rol del usuario